# What is the simplest local database I can use for my Android app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, couchbase

I don't want to be an expert or anything, I just need the simplest local database for android applications. I'm used to Parse (not local) but as it has been taken out I need a new one.
I've come accross SQLite and Couchbase Lite. I don't like the first one and I am not sure I can use Couchbase Lite only locally, without uploading my database to the server. Which do you recommend? Which is closer to Parse?
My application will save A LOT of data, so the database needs to be light, fast and with good documentation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/).

> Realm Mobile Database is an alternative to SQLite and Core Data. Thanks to its zero-copy design, Realm Mobile Database is much faster than an ORM, and often faster than raw SQLite.

In Addition, it has good documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Couchbase Lite purely as a local data store.  It's quite capable as is, and will be adding some very powerful features in the upcoming 2.0 version.

In terms of simplicity, I find it just about equivalent to regular file i/o in complexity, for basic use.